# reference other projects in visual studio for win32 projects

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I am working with win32 API and my language of choice is pure **C** and no **C++**.

Assume I have a project **A** that is present in Solution **S** in visual studio

I want to add another project **B**(which has some common utility functions) in to **S**

Now I want to reference Project **B** in Project **A**... So that I can use those utility functions from Project **B** source code level. I dont want it be used against dll of Project **B**

assume project B contains some math related functions and i want to call the functions from Project A or project B contains come data structures and i want to make use of them in Project A

How to achieve this.... thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you dont want project B to be a DLL, then it MUST be a static library. It project B is already an EXE, then you need to add a 3rd project: Project C - A static library project that contains the source files shared between A and B. Projects A and B can either reference it, or list it as a project dependency.

---

Ok. If you create a solution in Devstudio with projects, then the default layout on disk will be something like - having created a Project 3 as a static library project:

```
c:\Projects\SolutionDir
                       \Project1
                       \Project2
                       \Project3
```

Move the source (.cpp) AND header files (.h) for the common structs and functions to Project 3.

In projects A and B, find Project Settings > Compiler > Additional Includes and add an entry that says

```
$(SolutionDir)
```

Now, in projects1 and 2, you can reference the header files from Project3 thusly:

```
#include "Project3/commonheader.h"
// or
#include "Project1/sharedFunctionDecls.h"
#include "Project2/sharedStructDefs.h"
```

Right click on Project1 (and then Project 2) and choose "Project Dependencies..." and tick Project 3.

Comment: assume project B contains some math related functions and i want to call the functions from Project A or project B contains come data structures and i want to make use of them in Project A

Comment: No. Project C should contain the  math functions and data structures.

Comment: Great explanation Chris! Just ran into the same issue and this resolved it for me!! Thank you! 

Just one thing, I had to add a local reference to the project in order for mine to work. Perhaps I did it wrong, but having the project dependency ticked wasn't enough for me. Just in case anyone else hits this, adding the reference to it fixed it for me :)